# Find joint density function for $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}(x+y)e^{-x-y}$

Tags: probability, density-function

> If $X$ and $Y$ have joint density function
>   $$
> f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
> \frac{1}{2}(x+y)e^{-x-y}&\text{if }x,y>0,\\
> 0&\text{otherwise,}
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   find the density function of $Z=X+Y$.

I did the following:
$$
\begin{aligned}
f_Z(z)&=1/2\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\int_0^z\int_0^{z-x}(x+y)e^{-x-y}dydx\\
&=1/2\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\int_0^z\left[[-(x+y)e^{-x-y}]_0^{z-x}+\int_o^{z-x}e^{-x-y}\right]dx\\
&=1/2\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\int_0^z\left[-ze^{-z}+xe^{-x}+[-e^{-x-y}]_0^{z-x}\right]dx\\
&=1/2\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\int_0^z-ze^{-z}+xe^{-x}-e^{-z}+e^{-x}dx\\
&=1/2\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left[\int_0^z-ze^{-z}-e^{-z}+e^{-x})+\int_0^z xe^{-x}dx \right]\\
&=1/2\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left[(-z^2e^{-z}-ze^{-z}-e^{-z}+1)+\int_0^z xe^{-x}dx \right]\\
&=1/2\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left[-z^2e^{-z}-ze^{-z}-e^{-z}+1-ze^{-z}-e^{-z}+1\right]\\
&=1/2\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left[-z^2e^{-z}-2ze^{-z}-2e^{-z}+2\right]\\
&=1/2[-2ze^{-z}+z^2e^{-z}-2e^{-z}+2ze^{-z}+2e^{-z}]\\
&=1/2z^2e^{-z}.
\end{aligned}
$$

*EDIT*

Apparently, I can't use the fundamental theorem, but if I just finish the outer integral and then differentiate, then things go well.

Is there an easier approach though?

Answer (score 0):

Here I present you another way of doing it, which is much faster.

Probability fact:

> With $f(x,y)$, for any $Z=G(X,Y)$, $$f_Z(z)= \int\int f(x,y)\delta(z-G(x,y)) dxdy,$$ where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function.

For $Z=X+Y$, and $D$ is the positive $x$-$y$ plane,
\begin{align}
 f_Z(z) &=\int\int_D f(x,y)\delta(z-x-y) dxdy \\
        & = \frac{1}{2}z e^{-z} \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} dl \\
 & =\frac{1}{2}z^2 e^{-z} 
\end{align}

In the second equality, we have used $\int _{\mathbf {R} ^{2}}f(\mathbf {x} )\,\delta (g(\mathbf {x} ))\,d\mathbf {x} =\int _{g^{-1}(0)}{\frac {f(\mathbf {x} )}{|\mathbf {\nabla } g|}}\,dl$, here $g(\mathbf{x})=z-x-y,$ and $dl$ is the line element where $g(\mathbf{x})=0$. The facor of $1/\sqrt{2}$ comes from $|\mathbf {\nabla } g|$. In the last equality, we simply know that the integral is the length of the line connecting $(z,0)$, $(0,z)$.

Comment: hm, too bad I've never seen that before. I could also use the following, right:
$$
f_Z(z)=\int_0^zf(x,z-x)dx
$$
Basically the general convolution formula

Comment: The expression I've shown above can be derived easily, just write the first integral in your question using $\theta$-function, and then taking the derivative inside gives you the $delta$-function.